# Show that $S(f^{-1}(C))=f^{-1}(S(C))$

Tags: measure-theory

Show that $S(f^{-1}(C))=f^{-1}(S(C))$, where $f:X \to Y$ is a function and $C$ is a non empty family of subsets of $Y$. And $f^{-1}(C):=\{f^{-1}(c)|c \in C\}$ and $S(C)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$. 
I could show one sided inclusion by first showing that $f^{-1}(S(C))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and then using the fact that $f^{-1}(C) \subset f^{-1}(S(C)) $.

I am unable to show the other sided inclusion.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that 
$$
\mathcal{E}=\{B\subseteq Y\mid f^{-1}(B)\in S(f^{-1}(C))\}
$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra that obviously contains $C$. Thus, $S(C)\subseteq\mathcal{E}$, that is,
$$
f^{-1}(B)\in S(f^{-1}(C)),\quad B\in S(C).
$$
This is exactly equivalent to saying that $f^{-1}(S(C))\subseteq S(f^{-1}(C))$.